# How to find a patent lawyer for EEG / ECG electrodes?

Tags: lawyers

I have some provisional patents for new EEG and ECG dry electrodes that I think are pretty cool. Now I would like to file an official patent because I have talked to some people in the field and they agree that it is worth trying to patent.

What kind of patent lawyer would I contact for this? I can't tell whether the category is electrical or biological or medical something else. For context, EEG and ECG are the big machines that people use to read brainwaves and heart signals to tell if you have a mental or other ailment. However, this patent is primarily focused on consumer EEG/ECG electrodes, which would be used more for meditation and other techniques outside of medicine (in these areas, accuracy is less important than convenience, and these are convenient electrodes -- easy to apply and remove, etc).  I'm tempted to just Google "Patent lawyer NYC", but I think I remember reading somewhere that its best to file patents like these with a specialist.

Thanks

Comment: just ask yourself what the main improvement is - is it a new chemical compound as electrode gel? -> chemical expert. Or is it mainly about reading the eeg-signals with a different algorithm to be ale to use dry electrodes? -> electrical expert. Or look for someone who does all of it, biomedical engineer for example if it's mainly the eeg part. A law firm with chemists and electrical engineers if it's both.

Comment: @DonQuiKong pretty decent answer. Perhaps you should post it as such.

Comment: @EricShain It doesn't exactly answer how to find one, just what to search for

Answer (score 1):

This may seem far fetched, but you could do a patent search and when you find good patents in the field look up the attorneys who filed them.

Comment: Very time consuming, but actually a good idea.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I figured the OP would have to be searching for prior art anyway.

Comment: That's why it's a good idea ;-)